# Performing unit tests in a code behind file

Tags: wpf, unit-testing, nunit, code-behind

I'm implementing a WPF application using the MVVM pattern.

The application is basically a communications panel (comms panel) with control widgets laid on top of it (e.g., dial pads, intercom lines, etc). The control widgets have also been implemented using the MVVM pattern, as this allows us to easily test them on an individual basis.

A few hours ago, I posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12952871/binding-a-variable-inside-a-viewmodel-to-a-different-variable-in-another-viewmod) because I was having problems in order to link things between a DialPad and CommsPanels viewmodels. After a long chat with another SO member, I managed to get the link working. However, in doing that, I made heavy modifications in the DialPad code, such as getting rid of its model and moving the viewmodel code to the codebehind file. The problem is, not my unit tests are not working, mainly because NUnit is throwing an exception everytime I tried to instantiate a DialPad codebehind's class, which inherits from UserControl. Is there any way to write unit tests for a class that inherits from a WPF class (such as UserControl)?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

One option would be to take the important code from the code behind and put it in it's own class (that does not inherit from `UserControl`), which is then wrapped by the code behind.